# Getting error while using combinebykey in JavaDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting the below **error** while running the program. I am trying to find the average of the Dstream in the format (name,avg).

> 'The method combineByKey(Function, Function2,
>   Function2, Partitioner) in the type
>   JavaPairDStream is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Function,
>   Function2,
>   Function2)'

Please help.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class FirstSparkApplication {

     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class AvgCount implements java.io.Serializable {
            public AvgCount(double total, int num) {
              total_ = total;
              num_ = num;
            }
            public double total_;
            public int num_;
            public double avg() {
              return total_ / (double) num_;
            }
          }


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("FirstSparkApplication");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(20));
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);

    Function2<Double, Double, Double> reduceFunc = new Function2<Double, Double,
            Double>() {
    public Double call(Double result, Double value)
            throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Reduce running");
            System.out.println(result + "+" + value);
            return result + value;
            }
    };



    JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream("/home/dominic/Downloads/DATADIR").cache();

    final String[] path = new String[]{ "/home/dominic/Downloads/OUTPUTDIR"};

    JavaPairDStream<String, Double> pair = lines.flatMapToPair(

            new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, Double>() {


                private static final long serialVersionUID = 67676744;
                public Iterator<Tuple2<String, Double>> call(String t) throws Exception {

                        List<Tuple2<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Double>>();

                        JSONArray js1 = new JSONArray(t);

                        for (int i = 0; i < js1.length(); i++) {

                        String symbol = js1.getJSONObject(i).get("symbol")
                        .toString();

                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(js1.getJSONObject(i)
                        .get("priceData").toString());

                        list.add(new Tuple2<String, Double>(symbol,jo.getDouble("close")));

                        }

                        return list.iterator();

                        }
            });

    JavaPairDStream<String, Double> result=pair.reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduceFunc, Durations.seconds(100), Durations.seconds(60));


    pair.print();
    result.print();

    //Average
      Function<Double, AvgCount> createAcc = new Function<Double, AvgCount>() {
          public AvgCount call(Double x) {
            return new AvgCount(x, 1);
          }
        };
        Function2<AvgCount, Double, AvgCount> addAndCount = new Function2<AvgCount, Double, AvgCount>() {
          public AvgCount call(AvgCount a, Double x) {
            a.total_ += x;
            a.num_ += 1;
            return a;
          }
        };
        Function2<AvgCount, AvgCount, AvgCount> combine = new Function2<AvgCount, AvgCount, AvgCount>() {
          public AvgCount call(AvgCount a, AvgCount b) {
            a.total_ += b.total_;
            a.num_ += b.num_;
            return a;
          }
        };

    AvgCount initial = new AvgCount(0,0);


    JavaPairDStream<String, AvgCount> avgCounts = result.combineByKey(createAcc, addAndCount, combine);
//  Map<String, AvgCount> countMap = avgCounts.collectAsMap();
 //   for (Entry<String, AvgCount> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
 //     System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().avg());

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
    jssc.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Can you at least format your code?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `Partitioner` implementation in the call to `combineByKey`. That's what the compiler is telling you.

```
result.combineByKey(createAcc, addAndCount, combine /*, Partitioner here */);
```

It's a good habit to check the appropriate documentation once you get these kind of errors.
 See [Partitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaPairDStream.html).